# Tracking ADFS login with Google Tag Manager (GTM)

Tags: google-tag-manager, adfs, adfs3.0, adfs4.0

Anyone know how to add Google Tags into the ADFS screen? There doesn't appear to be any direct access to the underlying HTML of the login screen. Most of the ADFS screen customizing is done using a style sheet and onload.js.

Google searches seem to return 'how to guides' for using ADFS to login to GTM, which is the opposite of what I am after.